# definition of convergence in distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, smooth-functions

I'm reading the definition of convergence for distribution from [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf) and I cant seem to wrap my head around the notations. Can someone provide a simple explanation or perhaps in layman terms? :) thankyou

Comment: Is it Definition 7.1 that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to understand its definition or interpretation in a simpler sense

Comment: The definition says that the distribution sequence $(u_j)$ converges to $u$ if, for every choice of $\varphi$, the real (or complex) sequence $u_j(\varphi)$ converges to $u(\varphi)$.